# Confused by extremely high autocorrelation

Tags: correlation, python, autocorrelation, random-generation

I have the following python code

```
x = [100.0 for _ in range(1000)]
for i in range(1, len(x)):
     x[i] = x[i-1] + (2*randint(0, 1)-1)*step_size
import numpy as np
print np.corrcoef(x[:-1], x[1:])
```

I am getting extremely high correlation values, over 99.9%, more precisely

```
[[ 1.          0.99785636]
 [ 0.99785636  1.        ]]
```

Does anyone know what's going on? How can I get such large autocorrelation?

Comment: Hint: plot your simulated data.

Comment: You're simulating autocorrelated data. What is it about the fact that the result is autocorrelated that confuses you?

Comment: I guess I don't get it why the data is autocorrelated. I am making a random move on each step. Can you please elaborate on this? I don't know what makes this data autocorrelated. What would be an example of less autocorrelated data?

Comment: I plot the data, it looks like a straight line. Interesting, but still I lack deeper understanding as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is autocorrelated because the value for $x_i$ depends on the value of $x_{i-1}$. That is actually the definition of autocorrelation (loosely speaking). If you want non-autocorrelated data, you'd have to change your code to

```
x[i] = (2*randint(0, 1)-1)*step_size
```

i.e., remove `x[i-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are simulating a random walk. Any given period equals the previous period plus some random noise. As such, the theoretical correlation between successive periods is close to 1. Nothing unusual.